# Python Not Iterating Through a Loop More Than Once

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

I am new to Python and I'm trying out an exercise that models UPC codes in grocery stores. I need to multiply each digit in the list by 3 if its position is odd, and 1 if its position is even, then I need to sum all the results.

```
def upc_code(code):
    given_check_digit = code[-1]
    new_code = code[0:-1]
    list_of_numbers = list(map(int, new_code.strip()))
    how_many = len(list_of_numbers)
    new_lst = []
    counter = 1
    for item in range(1, how_many + 1):
        check_odd_even = item % 2
        for digit in list_of_numbers:
            if check_odd_even == 1:
            index_number = digit * 3
            new_lst.append(index_number)
            counter += 1
        else:
            index_number = digit * 1
            new_lst.append(index_number)
            counter += 1
        break
```

Using the step-through feature in Pycharm, I see that everything works well, it goes through the first loop and checks if the number is odd or even, then steps through the second loop and grabs the first item in the index. It checks if it's 1 or 0 and goes properly enters the if/else conditions. This is where the problem begins, when it iterates through the second loop (for digit in list_of_numbers) a second time, it does NOT grab the second index, third index, etc. it just stays at the first index number.

This is just the rest of my code, which does not matter.

```
result_of_sum = sum(new_lst)
check_digit = result_of_sum % 10
if 1 <= check_digit <= 9:
    print("Hello")
else:
    return False
```

If anyone could explain what I'm doing wrong, and why it's not going through the list properly in the second loop, that would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is that `break` there?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because `list_of_numbers = list(map(int, new_code.strip()))` is always of length `1`. So your `for` loop iterates once.

Comment: @Chris because if I don't put it there, the program iterates through the second loop before going back to the first. That won't be valid since the variable check_odd_even will always be 1 (odd) in that case and never 0 (even), meaning it's always multiplying by 3. 

However, you bring up a good question. When I remove the break, it iterates through the list. If I add the break back, it doesn't iterate through the list but it iterates through the first loop (which is what I need it to do).

Comment: Try putting that break statement in the `else` section